# Table-Per-SubClass not working

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

have a rather simple (or so I would think!) problem which is starting to annoy the hell out of me.

I have a simple set of classes.

The base Class "Product" is inherited by other classes, Product has a string Discriminator column "ProductType" which *should* allow NH to return the correct subclass.

Below is a simple version of what I am working on.

```
 public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {

        Table("Product");
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .GeneratedBy.Identity();

        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("ProductType");


        Map(x => x.Name)
            .Length(200);
        Map(x => x.BriefDescription)
            .Length(400);

        Map(x => x.FullDescription);

        Map(x => x.Sku);
        Map(x => x.VendorSku);

        References(x => x.Vendor, "VendorId");


    }
}

public class MotorHomeMap : SubclassMap<MotorHome>
{
    public MotorHomeMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("MotorHome");

        Table("MotorHome");


        //KeyColumn("ProductId");
        Map(x => x.Berths);


    }
}
```

However if I do a simple Session.QueryOver.List() the resulting query that gets executed is

```
SELECT this_.Id               as Id1_0_,
   this_.Name             as Name1_0_,
   this_.BriefDescription as BriefDes4_1_0_,
   this_.FullDescription  as FullDesc5_1_0_,
   this_.Sku              as Sku1_0_,
   this_.VendorSku        as VendorSku1_0_,
   this_.VendorId         as VendorId1_0_,
   this_.Berths           as Berths1_0_,
   this_.ProductType      as ProductT2_1_0_
```

FROM   Product this_

Obviously "Berths" is NOT in the Product table, rather it is in the "MotorHome" table.

I'm sure I'm missing something rather simple but cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying `DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn` you are configuring the mapping to be table-per-class-hierarchy and not table-per-subclass

[Fluent mapping documentation on subclasses](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#Subclasses)

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel rather stupid now. Definitely a major case of RTFM (properly)